# Windows Phone App Crash

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I recently uploaded a game to the Windows Phone Marketplace and after a few days I got a crash report with the following Exception `system.invalidoperationexception` and the following stack trace report

```
0        Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll    System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.GoForwardBackCore        0x000bcb8e    
1        Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll    System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.GoBack                   0x000000ec    
2        BlocksPhone.ni.DLL        BlocksPhone.MainPage.btnExitClick                                    0x0000001e    
3        System.Windows.ni.dll     System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick                0x00000030    
4        System.Windows.ni.dll     System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick                               0x0000001e    
5        System.Windows.ni.dll     System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp    0x00000132    
6        System.Windows.ni.dll     System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp                  0x00000034    
7        System.Windows.ni.dll     MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent                                     0x00000334
```

I understand that the app could crash because of the exit button click event but I am unsure of what exactly would have caused the crash. Report says that the crash was on `Apollo` Version.
This is my exit button click event..

```
private void btnExitClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  this.NavigationService.GoBack();
}
```

Comment: I thought exiting an app was against the guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `GoBack()` when `CanGoBack` is false will throw this exception. Also, This is not the right way to exit your app because it will throw`InvalidOperationException` when called in your `MainPage`.

Read [Exiting a Windows Phone Application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/01/exiting-a-windows-phone-application.aspx) for several methods to correctly exit a WP app.

Answer (score 0):

Maby forget put to some inization code to
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
and application crash for uninitalized control.

Apollo is WP8.